# UVMap won't apply

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work. It did work at one point fully textured did some weight painting now won't texture. I attached my blender file, any help is appreciated.

http://www.filedropper.com/hellscream

Comment: The UV map is there, there's just no material with texture applied to the object. Is there an image texture to apply or are you just using the green/orange cloud texture in the file?

Comment: Interesting. I usually find walls more painful to bang my head against. [I usually use my desk.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30417798#30417798)

Comment: There can be only one! O.o

Comment: This question needs a LOT more information. Keep in mind, this is not a forum. You've basically just dumped a blender file here and asked for a diagnosis. State the problem, describe what you've tried, ask a clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a Material to your object, then set up a texture (Image or Procedural), and use it to drive colour on your object, with Mapping type set to UV, and your UV map selected.

You also need to add a lamp to your scene so the object isn't pure black.

Comment: How exactly is that done, I add the material but I do not see the option to add UV map? ----- I got it. Thanks a bunch, just spent countless hours doing this, was about to give up =P

Comment: No problem, glad to help!